# How to Insert a floating Disclaimer in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting

I have a Google spreadsheet that contains a disclaimer at the top (the disclaimer works as a Warning Message). However i would like this disclaimer to go down as I scroll. The **freezing pannel function** is not good for me because i only want the disclaimer to go down. Someone can help me with the scrip for that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You can use [custom sidebars](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_sidebars) to show your disclaimer.

**Sample Code.gs:**

```
function showSidebar() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Page')
      .setTitle('Disclaimer');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .showSidebar(html);
}
```

**Sample Page.html:** (You can look for HTML tutorials online, here's one [reference](https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp))

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
  
    <h1 style="color:red"> DISCLAIMER </h1>

    Hello, world! This is a disclaimer ........<br>
    <br>
    You can add more information here
    
  </body>
</html>
```

**Output:**

[image]

---

You can also use this script as an onOpen [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable), so that whenever the file is being opened, the custom sidebar will be shown automatically.

**To [manually create an installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) in the script editor, follow these steps:**

[image]

**Sample Config:**

[image]